# Error assigning a value to a constructed variable in R

Tags: r

I'm fairly new to R programming.  Can someone say why this code keeps giving an error : `paste0("emissions_for_",yr) <- sum(nei_tst[,var][select_obs], na.rm=TRUE)`

- (nei_tst is a dataframe)
- (var is a variable that was assigned the name of one column in that dataframe)
- select_obs is a variable with logical elements (result of test : yr == "1999")

I get the foll. error :  `Error in paste0("emissions_for_", yr) <- sum(nei_tst[, var][select_obs],  : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object`

Comment: Without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it's not easy to provide you with specifics. I think you want something like `tapply(nei_tst[,var], nei_tst$yr, sum, na.rm=TRUE)` will give you the result you want. Building variable names like they are strings is just not a good idea in R and often makes things much more difficult to work with. I strongly suggest you avoid this strategy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `assign` if the name of the object is stored as a character string:

```
assign(paste0("emissions_for_",yr), sum(nei_tst[,var][select_obs], na.rm=TRUE))
```

However, creating multiple variables dynamically to store multiple values in not good R style. You should store all related values in a single object, e.g., a list or a data frame.

Comment: @MrFlick Agreed. I added a comment.

Comment: Thanks guys...as simple as that ?!!  (Mr. Flick, I think you actually helped me answer another question as well).

Answer (score 0):

Might you not be better off to create a dataframe, and index by year?

```
emissions <- data.frame(yr, sum(nei_tst[,var][select_obs], na.rm=TRUE))
```